# Convert hour interval to 24h interval

Tags: java, android, string, date, converters

I would like to convert "9:00 am – 11:00 pm" -> "9:00 - 23:00", how can I do that? What I've tried so far:

```
if(input.contains("am")) {  //This because I have a string with other kind of items too (not only these interval of hours but names, etc)

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a – h:mm a");
    DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - HH:mm");
    Date date = null;
    String output = null;
    date= df.parse(input);
    input = outputformat.format(date);
    System.out.println("Output: "+output);
```

}

but the output is wrong, in the example 23:00 - 23:00 because it doesn't recognize the first and the second hour

I tried also something like:

```
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a" +" - "+ "h:mm a");
     DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"+" - "+ "HH:mm");
```

but I got a parse error then

Comment: From the looks of it the output should be `null` (since you're printing `output` which was only defined as `String output = null`), so please post something that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: What is the `string` variable that you pass to the `parse` method!?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was not date= df.parse(string); but date= df.parse(input); 

If I insert a println after the if I correctly get a list of string of type "9:00 am – 11:00 pm". The if works correctly

Example of input and output I have with the current code:



I/System.out: Input 9:00 am – 11:00 pm

I/System.out: Output: 23:00 - 23:00


I/System.out: Input: 8:00 am – 5:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 17:00 - 17:00

I/System.out: Input: 4:00 am – 12:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 12:00 - 12:00

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please add it in the question itself rather than in a comment so we have everything in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String dateToParse = "9:00 am – 11:00 pm";
        String splitDate[] = dateToParse.split("–");

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
        String output1 = null, output2 = null;
        try {
            date1 = df.parse(splitDate[0].trim());
            date2 = df.parse(splitDate[1].trim());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output1 = outputformat.format(date1);
        output2 = outputformat.format(date2);

        System.out.println("Output: " + output1 + " – " + output2);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works except for the case where I have 12pm:

I/System.out: Input: 9:00 am – 11:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 09:00 – 23:00
I/System.out: Input: 9:00 am – 11:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 09:00 – 23:00
I/System.out: Input: 9:00 am – 11:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 09:00 – 23:00
I/System.out: Input: 8:00 am – 5:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 08:00 – 17:00
I/System.out: Input: 4:00 am – 12:00 pm
I/System.out: Output: 04:00 – 12:00

As you can see in the last 2 lines, 12 pm is converted as 12 but it's wrong, it should be 00:00. 12 am is 12 instead.

Comment: 12:00 pm is noon and 12:00 am is mid night. 4:00 am – 12:00 am (Output: 04:00 – 00:00)  and 4:00 am – 12:00 pm (Output: 04:00 – 12:00)

Answer (score 1):

### Go object-oriented and use java.time

Don’t convert your interval from one string format to another. Design an `Interval` class for storing and manipulating your time intervals. I suggest that you include a convenience constructor that accepts a string and a `toString` method that produces your desired format.

I furthermore recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work.

```
public class Interval {

    private static final String middlePart = " – ";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter amPmFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("h:mm a")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    private LocalTime begin;
    private LocalTime end;
    
    public Interval(String intervalString) {
        String[] timeStrings = intervalString.split(middlePart);
        if (timeStrings.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Improper format");
        }
        begin = LocalTime.parse(timeStrings[0], amPmFormatter);
        end = LocalTime.parse(timeStrings[1], amPmFormatter);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + begin + middlePart + end;
    }
}
```

To try it out:

```
        Interval testInterval = new Interval("9:00 am – 11:00 pm");
        System.out.println(testInterval);
```

Output is:

> 09:00 – 23:00

### What went wrong in your code?

`Date` is the completely wrong class to use for your interval. The class is poorly designed and long outdated. A `date` represents a point in time, not a time of day and certainly not an interval of two times of day.

`SimpleDateFormat` — a notorious troublemaker of a class — tried to parse your string into a time of January 1, 1970 in your time zone. It should have objected because a time on that day cannot be both 9 AM and 11 PM — you were contradicting yourself. But no, `SimpleDateFormat` gives you one of those times, keeps its mouth shut and pretends all is well. Possibly an attempt to be nice, but if so, IMHO a completely misunderstood attempt.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.